# Why does a request is error from apk but from postman its good?

Tags: mysql, apk, google-cloud-sql

I have an application that suppose to be in google play in one day.
yesterday everything was great before we updated our last apk vaersion.
now the mysql google cloud sql database doesnt responds to apk request but from postman eveything good. what could it be?

```
http://34.77.45.90/api/Categories/
```

this is the postman request that works well. (with GET).

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
baseRoute:"http://34.77.45.90/api/"

};

getcategories(): any {
return this.http.get(environment.baseRoute+"Categories/")
.toPromise().then(
res => { 
this.cateroriesArr=res;
console.log(res);
return res;
})
.catch(err => { return false;})
}
```

the problem is the get request.

Comment: you sure you updated your manifest to allow [internet/sockets connections](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)? -> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> `

Comment: Hi. i changed it but its still didnt work. the weird thing is that in some networks the app is fine and in another many networks tha app doeasnt work. please help me!!

Comment: @riki is it working now?

Comment: no. probably the problem is the ssl certificate i dont have. cause in public networks tha app is fine. we are working on it... tnx anyway.